# How to make logging in rails libs works like in models and controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, libraries

So far I always used "puts" to add custom logging infos to my code. But now it is kind of a pain. When I run rspec for exemple I'm not interested in all the verbose that I added with puts. So I installed the "logging and logging-rails gem" because its installation is real fast and satisfying.

It works well when I call logger from models and controller, but not when I'm using logger inside libraries. I get that error : NameError - undefined local variable or method `logger' for CustomLib:Class.

The easiest thing I succeeded is to call 'Rails.logger' instead of just 'logger'. But in that way in my logfile, the class referring to that line will be 'Rails' but I want 'CustomLib'. For models and controller the right classname is displayed without any intervention from myself.

```rb
  # config/environnement/test.rb

  # Set the logging destination(s)
  config.log_to = %w[stdout]
  config.log_level = :info

  # Show the logging configuration on STDOUT
  config.show_log_configuration = false
```

```rb
  # lib/custom_lib.rb
  class CustomLib
    def initialize
      Rails.logger.info 'foo'
    end
  end
```

When I will use or test my customlib class I'll get :
[2019-06-21T16:26:41] INFO  Rails : foo

Instead I would like to see :
[2019-06-21T16:26:41] INFO  CustomLib : foo

I'm a bit lost in all that log management in rails, I have no idea what to try next to reach that goal...

### Edit

When I put a byebug just before the "logger.info 'foo' " line and enter into it via 'step', I got two different results if whether I'm in a model/controller or a custom lib.

```
# In custom lib, step enters this file "gems/logging-2.2.2/lib/logging/logger.rb"
# And Rails.logger returns an object like this one beloow
Logging::Logger:0x000055a2182f8f40
  @name="Rails",
  @parent=#<Logging::RootLogger:0x000055a2182e7ee8 
    @name="root",
    @level=1>,

# In model/controller, step enters this file "gems/logging-rails-0.6.0/lib/logging/rails/mixin.rb"
# And Rails.logger returns an object like this one beloow
Logging::Logger:0x0000557aed75d7b8
  @name="Controller",
  @parent=#<Logging::RootLogger:0x0000557aedfcf630
    @name="root",
    @level=0>,
```

Comment: I guess there may be a class that CustomLib should inherits to have the expected behavior ?

Comment: When I make my class inherits from ApplicationController it works as I expect it. But it feels wrong, what is the specific class I should use for my purpose ?

Comment: Works with ActionController::Base too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I found a better way, I just need to include Logging.globally on top of the module where I want that behavior:

```rb
# lib/custom_lib.rb
class CustomLib
  include Logging.globally
 
  def initialize
    logger.info 'foo'
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

The `Rails` in the log line is [the `progname` of the logger](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/logger.rb#L597). You could create a new logger that sets the progname to `'CustomLib'`with (say) `Rails.logger.clone.tap {|l| l.progname = 'CustomLib' }`, but that isn't really the purpose of `progname`, which is to specify the name of the *program*, not the name of a class.

You could instead include the class name in the log line:

```
Rails.logger.info "[#{self.class}] - some message"
```

Or, for a bit more effort, you could define your own formatter. Here's one with a convenience method for wrapping an existing logger:

```
class ClassNameFormatter
  def self.wrap_logger(klass, logger)
    logger.clone.tap { |l| l.formatter = new(klass, logger.formatter) }
  end

  def initialize(klass, formatter=nil)
    @klass = klass
    @formatter = formatter ||= Logger::Formatter.new
  end

  def call(severity, timestamp, progname, msg)
    @formatter.call severity, timestamp, progname, "[#{@klass.name}] - #{msg}"
  end
end
```

To use it:

```
class CustomLib
  def initialize
    @logger = ClassNameFormatter.wrap_logger self.class, Rails.logger
  end

  def call
    @logger.info 'test log please ignore'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your developed answer. I like the idea of changing the progname to display what we want. But I'm not using the default Rails logger, instead it is the one provided by logging and logging-rails gem. What is returned for logger is a Logging::Logger object.

When I put a byebug just before the "logger.info 'foo' " line and enter into it via 'step', I got two different results. I'm editing my question because it won't hold here.